# Login system variable of account page error

Tags: php, html, variables, global-variables

This is the code. I wanted my website login system. As a member successfully logins (variable login) returns true if not returns false.

When I insert this code
*When user login was incorrect it shows the code for Successful login.

Always it pretend to show the successful login code even a user login was wrong.

```
<?php
include_once "header.php";
$access = $_REQUEST['login'];

if ($access==true)
{
    echo "Welcome<p>";
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="upload.html">UPLOAD AND SHARE FILES</a><p>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
if ($access==false)
{
    echo "Your Login Details Invalid.<p>";
    echo "Please go to mazker.tk and Retry Login or Sign Up";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is `$_REQUEST['login'];` returning?

Answer (score 1):

try it working or not.

```
$access = $_REQUEST['login'];

if($access==true)
{
echo "Welcome<p>";
}
```

instead of use this code.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['login']))
{
echo "Welcome<p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, I'm not writing a exact code , I'm just showing you a demo for that.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if(!empty($name) && !empty($password)){
loginUser($name,$password);
}
// fetch values from database 
function loginUser($name,$password){
if($db_name==$name && $db_password==$password){
//return true condition from here
}else{
// return false condition here
}
}
```